# Can I lift tag-wiki entries from other SE sites?

Tags: discussion

I'm currently asking questions that don't seem to have a tag-wiki entry for the tags I need to use, and there's perfectly good tags on SU for those pieces of software. Can I copy the tag wiki information from SU (and how would I attribute?) to help initially populate these tags?

Comment: That kind of depends on what information is on Super User. Tag wikis and excerpts are supposed to direct users on the *proper use of the tag on this site*. If you're thinking of just pasting in a huge description of the product without direction, I'd advise against that. Background information can be useful, but should not be the focus (the tag wiki should not effectively be an advertisement).

Comment: Only when its appropriate - that said, any changes I'd make here would be the same changes I'd make for a SU page.

Answer (score 3):

All content on SE is CC :)

I wrote a lot of the tag wikis on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), so I have no problem copying my own content. But even copying from other users' tag wiki edits shouldn't pose a problem in terms of "being stolen/borrowed".

However, there are things to consider when doing so: a 1:1 copy only fits in rare cases. In most cases, adjustments are needed to reflect the tag's purpose on the specific site. The very same tag might serve a completely different purpose on another site. To give a somehow "heavy" example: On A.SE we deal with "Android issues from the *users'* point of view", and development questions are strictly off-topic. So you shouldn't make a 1:1 copy of our `java` and `development` tags :)